# conversion from any base to base 10 c++

Tags: c++, base-conversion

I found two ways of conversion from any base to base 10 . the first one is the normal one we do in colleges like 521(base-15)  ---> (5*15^2)+(2*15^1)+(1*15^0)=1125+30+1 = 1156 (base-10) . my problem is that i applied both methods to a number (1023456789ABCDE(Base-15)) but i am getting different result . google code jam accepts the value generated from second method only for this particular number (i.e 1023456789ABCDE(Base-15)) . for all other cases both generates same results . whats big deal with this special number ?? can anybody suggest ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   //number in base 15 is 1023456789ABCDE
    int value[15]={1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    int base =15;
    unsigned long long sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        sum+=(pow(base,i)*value[14-i]);
    }
    cout << sum << endl; 
    //this prints 29480883458974408
    sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        sum=(sum*base)+value[i];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    //this prints 29480883458974409
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that 1023456789ABCDE base 15 is a very large number.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `std::stol`([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) to convert a string into a long.
It let you choose the base to use, here an example for your number wiuth base `15`.

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "1023456789ABCDE";
    long n = std::stol(s,0,15);
    std::cout<< s<<" in base 15: "<<n<<std::endl;
    // -> 1023456789ABCDE in base 15: 29480883458974409
}
```

Comment: this one is really helpful , i tried your code but have to change long n to unsigned long long and stol to stoull because converted number is very large 10^18 . any ways thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`pow(base, i)` uses floating point and so you loose some precision on some numbers.

Comment: Right. `double` is generally only good for no more than 16 digits, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1):

Exceeded `double` precision.

Precision of `double`, the return value from `pow()`, is precise for at least `DBL_DIG` significant decimal digits.  `DBL_DIG` is at *least* 10 and typically is 15 [IEEE 754 double-precision binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).

The desired number `29480883458974409` is 17 digits, so some calculation error should be expected.

In particular, `sum += pow(base,i)*value[14-i]` is done as a `long long = long long + (double * long long)` which results in `long long = double`.  The nearest `double` to `29480883458974409` is `29480883458974408`.  So it is not an imprecise value from `pow()` that causes the issue here, but an imprecise sum from the addition.

@Mooing Duck in a comment references code to avoid using `pow()` and its `double` limitation`.  Following is a slight variant.

```
unsigned long long ullongpow(unsigned value, unsigned exp) {
  unsigned long long result = !!value;
  while (exp-- > 0) {
    result *= value;
  }
  return result;
}
```